# Multiples values para un select

Tags: angular

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Angular en mi frontend y Laravel en mi backend, tengo un problema a la hora tomar los datos de un select. El select toma una opción y esta opción en la api trae varios valores: Codigo, SectorDer y Descripcion. Yo quiero que a la hora de guardar estos datos con un post en mi base de datos me guarde esos 3 campos según la opción seleccionada.
Ahora mismo paso mis datos por el value y uso un ngModel. Mi idea era agregar otro [value] para que quede [value]="consulta.Codigo" y [value]="consulta.SectorDer"

tramite.component.html

```
      <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select name="CodTramite" placeholder="Tramite"  [(ngModel)]="this.tramitesService.newTramite.CodTramite">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let consulta of consultas"   [value]="consulta.Codigo">
        {{ consulta.Descripcion }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

No utilices otro value porque sobrescribiría los valores, lo que yo normalmente hago para estos casos es o llamar otro [(ngModel)] para guardar lo que necesitamos ("la manera fácil") o utilizar los valores seleccionados para hacer un consumo al servicio que me retorne lo que necesitamos de lo seleccionado (supongamos que la consulta se hizo por medio de un id)

Comment: Este ngModel del que me hablas lo tengo que poner en el mismo select? Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: no, lo pones en la opción

Comment: amigo porfa dale en aceptar a la respuesta sí te ha sido útil